# image icon not appearing outside eclipse

Tags: java, image, jar, icons, embedded-resource

I made a chess game with a gui, using images for the pieces. It works perfectly when run in eclipse. However, I tried exporting the jar (from eclipse) and running it in cmd but none of the images appear (the game itself however works perfectly, i just have to guess where the pieces are).
I'm going to assume that there is an issue with the addresses of the images... 
The problem is, I can't even seem to be able to open any of the files within the jar file to see what, if anything is going on.

In eclipse, all the images were in a package within the scr folder, and they are definitely within the jar.

Any advice?

Comment: What is the code used to load an image?

Comment: Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: "image= new ImageIcon("src/ChessGraphics/WhiteK.png");"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load images within your jar file you will need to use the 
`Class.getResource(String)` method.

For detailed instructions see the [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) section in the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. 

I replaced "image= new ImageIcon("src/ChessGraphics/WhiteK.png");" with " image= new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/ChessGraphics/WhiteK.png"));"